# How to get a id of string array from Strings.xml without direct id reference

Tags: android, android-listview, arrays

I have a number of arrays stored in Strings.xml file in my android project. I want to populate a list from these `Arrays` based upon a button click. depends upon which button clicked, i need to populate different lists. So the code is very messy by adding a nested `if else` structure. Is there any way to get the `String Array` from the `Strings.xml` where i can call it using a single common method for all. I am keeping the same name for button tag and array name. please help....`

current code is

```
if(submit_button.getTag().toString.equalsIgnoreCase("vacation"){
return getResources().getStringArray(R.array.vacation);
}
else if(submit_button.getTag().toString.equalsIgnoreCase("summer"){
return getResources().getStringArray(R.array.summer);
}
else if(submit_button.getTag().toString.equalsIgnoreCase("monsoon"){
return getResources().getStringArray(R.array.monsoon);
}
else if(submit_button.getTag().toString.equalsIgnoreCase("automn"){
return getResources().getStringArray(R.array.automn);
}
else if(submit_button.getTag().toString.equalsIgnoreCase("rainy"){
return getResources().getStringArray(R.array.rainy);
}
else if(submit_button.getTag().toString.equalsIgnoreCase("humid"){
return getResources().getStringArray(R.array.humid);
}
else if(submit_button.getTag().toString.equalsIgnoreCase("sunny"){
return getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sunny);
}
else{
return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this method to get the array id from array name..

```
private int getArrayId(String arranameString) {

    int id = this.getResources().getIdentifier(arranameString, "array", this.getPackageName());

    return id;

}
```

This will return the id of your string array

Comment: there is no need to parsing it into Long.

Answer (score 3):

```
<string-array name="myarray">
    <item>value1</item>
    <item>value2</item>
    <item>value3</item>
    <item>value4</item>
</string-array>
```

And in your java code,

```
String[] MyArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myarray);
```

I hope this is what you need, If not please let me know.

Comment: `Is there any way to get the String Array from the Strings.xml where i can call it using a single common method for all.` That is why I am giving this solution, if not may I know what he is asking exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You use this code;

**For string:**

```
public static int getImageResourceIDFromName(String tag,
            Context context) {

        int identifier = context.getResources().getIdentifier (tag,"string",context.getPackageName());
        return identifier;  
    }
```

**For Array:**

```
public static int getImageResourceIDFromName(String tag,
            Context context) {

        int identifier = context.getResources().getIdentifier (tag,"array",context.getPackageName());
        return identifier;  
    }
```

You need to pass name of identifier then it will return ids of that particular resource it will help you create lots `if else` statement,